# TeleBot.register_next_step_handler() got multiple values for argument 'message'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Пишу телеграмм бота. Задача заключатеся в следующем. Программа спрашивает, хочет ли пользователь добавить слово в словарь. Если да, то слово добавляется в словарь. В обоих случаях, я должен переходить на свою *main* функцию (choose_level_func), которая принимает: message, value. Но я получаю ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

```
def first_failure(message, value):

    send_lost = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты проиграл!')
    key = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Да', callback_data= 'yes')
    no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Нет', callback_data= 'no')
    key.add(yes, no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"добавить его в наш словарик?", reply_markup=key)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send_lost, ask_to_add, message)
        

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def ask_to_add(c, *args):
    global random_word
    if c.data == 'yes':
        cont_game = bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, "Хорошо, я добавил, продолжаем играть!\nЧтобы закончить играть введи: стоп")
        user_dict_with_words[random_word.capitalize()] = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='russian').translate(random_word).capitalize()
        print(user_dict_with_words)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(cont_game, choose_level_func, message='')

    if c.data == 'no':
        bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, "Хорошо, продолжаем!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(cont_game, choose_level_func, message='')
```

Comment: Нельзя совмещать колбек и register_next_step_handler

Comment: Как-то можно это обойти?

Comment: А зачем вам register_next_step_handler? Просто не используйте его